# Trying to make an async function that runs forever using run_forever

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

I am trying to access a websocket to listen to some information and so I want to use the run_forever command to keep listening until I stop the program, but when I do I get the error below, could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def listen():
    url = "websocket url starting with wss"

    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        msg = await ws.recv()
        print(msg)


loop.run_forever(listen())
```

the error then says:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'listen' was never awaited
  loop.run_forever(listen())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...", line 18, in <module>
    loop.run_forever(listen())
TypeError: run_forever() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: You are running the listen function as soon as giving it as parameter to `run_forever`. Try `run_forever(listen)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried loading your script into Python 3.9.6 and i saw your error.

This is how i got it to run (you need to enter the proper URL):

```
import asyncio, websockets

async def listen():
    url = "websocket url starting with wss"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        msg = await ws.recv()
        print(msg)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever(await listen())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I hope it can help you to get further with your program.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for! thank you :)

Comment: @kc.chvz You are welcome, feel free to accept my answer. :-)

Comment: Ohh got it! so sorry I am new to stackoverflow :D, have a nice day